# how to build postgres json query for missing property in json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table A with a column b as jsonb

```
        b
------------------
 {"c": 1}
 {"c": 1, "d": 2}
```

how to build a query for rows where d is missing?

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE b@>'{"c":1}';
```

returns all rows while

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE b@>'{"c":1,"d":null}';
```

returns none ( due d is not null in first row );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `?` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to test for the presence of a key. To find those where the key does not exist, you can negate the expression:

```
select *
from a 
where not b ? 'd';
```